# Can I put Wingpanel at the bottom of the screen?

Tags: wingpanel

Plank can be moved around with elementary Tweaks, so I was wondering, can Wingpanel also be moved?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it is not possible at the moment and there are currently no plans to add this feature.

Comment: Yeah, the code ;)

Comment: No sure what you want to achive? So you think if we answer questions here we shoud back them up with code lines or what? No thanks. Beside that if there is no support i can not reference something.

Comment: @Tim You can't really reference a lack of something in code. That doesn't make sense. Should he point to the folder where that file would go if it existed? :p But also djax is a developer working on wingpanel and his answer is accurate.

Comment: @Tim I'm not sure what you expect to link to? Again, how can you link to an absence of something? I can verify the answer is complete and accurate.

Comment: Guys, you're right, I'm sorry. I made a mistake here. http://meta.elementaryos.stackexchange.com/q/32/3